# Call Async Module from custom FormController

Tags: 2sxc

I need to call a custom **DLL** which has *async* calls to an *API*. I'm customising *Mobius Forms App*.

I've got stuck on the requirement that you can only call use the *await* operator from an *async* method.

If I make the *ProcessForm* method *Async*, I get the following exception:

```
AbsoluteURL:
DefaultDataProvider:DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, DotNetNuke
ExceptionGUID:4064be2b-8f04-4901-8b38-17eb9de37837
AssemblyVersion:
PortalId:-1
UserId:-1
TabId:-1
RawUrl:
Referrer:
UserAgent:
ExceptionHash:yaIM8BQCHlxRCrt3EOwJqHPijZ4=
Message:Thread was being aborted.
StackTrace:
   at System.Threading.Thread.SleepInternal(Int32 millisecondsTimeout)
   at DotNetNuke.Services.Scheduling.Scheduler.CoreScheduler.Start()
InnerMessage:
InnerStackTrace:
Source:mscorlib
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may simply not be implemented yet. Here some background

When a URL comes in which looks like a 2sxc API, the 2sxc engine will see if it finds an XXXController.cs and compile it. It then returns that to the .net / DNN API management which will then invoke the code, map parameters etc.

I could imagine that for async to work, it would need to support another interface or something. My guess is it's not a big deal, but I would need some example to start with, so I could help implement it.

Could you:

1. Create an issue on https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/issues
2. Add some more information on these async calls
3. Ideally with some example (not in 2sxc, but C# and .net 4.8) which does this?
4. Ideally it would actually be a DNN example, so I don't have to worry if DNN might actually block this or cause issues.

thx!

Comment: I've got it calling the async dll, but it's not working. I'll do a bit more work and follow up.

Comment: thanks, please share your findings - I'm sure others will benefit!

Comment: I ended up getting this to work just writing my own module in c#. In the end that was simpler than using 2sxc for this application. What I did find was the PageAsyncTask class, that would probably work with 2sxc if anyone else is needing to do this.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.pageasynctask?view=netframework-4.8